# How to save 2D arrays in the database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to save a 2D int array in my database with Entity Framework. But this way is not working:

```
public int[,] Board { get; set; } = new int[,]
    {
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    };
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: You have no code for “this way”, please include the code, so we can help you

Comment: With entity framework each table is a List object of the database.  so the top level is db which contains all the tables like table1, table2 table3.  Each table is a List<> object where each index is a row of the table.  The columns of the data can vary and you have to check the database to find out the type of object.  You can have 8 columns in the row one for each piece of data.  There may be a header on each row that contains a time and an index.  Or you list of 8 numbers may go into a single column.  I can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

A regular representation of a Board (bi-dynamical) array would be

```
public class Column
{
    public int BoardID { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    public int BoardID { get; set; }
    public int ColumnID { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class Board
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework works with entities sets, so usually you'll want to "tangibilize" your concept into a entity-driven aproach. Note, in this case, you would need to have three tables instead of only the X, Y representation of the raw array.

From here you'd just need to

```
dbContext.BOARD_TABLE.Add(myBoardInstance);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

And your board's instance, including children cols and rows, would be saved to DB thanks to the Board-Column 1-N and Column-Row 1-N relationship.